# How to store CLLocationCoordinate2D?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocation, parse-platform

I'm attempting to build an application that builds and saves routes similar to map my run. I'm using the [Breadcrumb](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010048) sample code, specifically the `CrumbPath` and `CrumbPathView` as the base of my routes, from Apple. Two questions:

1. If I try to access the `MKMapPoint *points` object of the `CrumbPath` like so:

   ```
   [_route lockForReading];
   NSLog(@"%@", _route.points);
   NSLog(@"%d", _route.pointCount);
   [_route unlockForReading];
   ```

   my app crashes, saying:

   ```
   Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code: 1, address: 0x9450342d)
   ```

   Which I have a hard time understanding, because within the `CrumbPath.m` file, the folks at apple write to the "array" by explicitly acquiring the write lock, and then unlocking it, but if I acquire the read lock and attempt to read from it, it crashes.
2. The reason I attempt to access the `points` is in an attempt to get the `MKMapPoints`, convert them to `CLLocationCoordinate2D` objects, and save them so I can redraw the `polyline` at the user's request. Since I cannot get access to the `points`, I attempt to save the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` objects from my `locationManager` that I send to the `_route` in an array to upload to my [Parse](http://parse.com) backend, but I always get an error saying:

   ```
   Sending 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'
   ```

   Which isn't making this any easier. Does anybody have any insight to why I'm getting these errors?

**Location Manager Delegate**

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    if (_userLocation.longitude != manager.location.coordinate.longitude
        && _userLocation.latitude != manager.location.coordinate.latitude) {
        _userLocation = manager.location.coordinate;
    }

    if (_isRecording) {
        if (!_route) {
            NSLog(@"lat: %f, lng: %f", _userLocation.latitude, _userLocation.longitude);
            _route = [[CrumbPath alloc] initWithCenterCoordinate:_userLocation];
            [_mapView addOverlay:_route];

            MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(_userLocation, 2000, 2000);
            [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
        }else {
            MKMapRect updateRect = [_route addCoordinate:_userLocation];

            if (!MKMapRectIsNull(updateRect)) {
                MKZoomScale currentZoomScale = (CGFloat)(_mapView.bounds.size.width / _mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width);
                CGFloat lineWidth = MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(currentZoomScale);
                updateRect = MKMapRectInset(updateRect, -lineWidth, -lineWidth);
                [_routeView setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:updateRect];
            }
        }
        [_routePoints addObject:_userLocation];

        [_route lockForReading];
        NSLog(@"%d", _route.pointCount);
        NSLog(@"%@", _route.points);
        [_route unlockForReading];
    }
}
```

**Stop Recording Logic**

```
    //stop recording
    NSLog(@"STOP");
    if (_route) {
        NSLog(@"There is a route");
        //Show route options toolbar
        [_route lockForReading];

        NSLog(@"%@", _route);
        NSLog(@"%d", _route.pointCount);
        NSLog(@"%@", _route.points);

        PFObject *routeToSave = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Routes"];
        //[routeToSave setObject:_route forKey:@"routePoints"];

        [_route unlockForReading];

        [routeToSave saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"%c", succeeded);
            }else {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", _route.pointCount);` is this an integer? Then you should use `%d`

Comment: well, yeah. sorry, I typed this up real quick. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Is it crashing even after that? and how are you calling the method with `CLLocationCoordinate2D` objects? Can you post that code?

Comment: MKMapPoint is a C struct, not an Objective-C class.

Comment: correction, the pointCount worked. adding code to OP now

Comment: @HighFlyingFantasy, Good to know that. Please check my answer for the second issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding your first issue, the crash was because of this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", _route.pointCount);
```

It should be:

```
NSLog(@"%d", _route.pointCount);
```

As mentioned in my comments, `%d` should be used for count and `%@` will cause a crash.

Regarding your second issue, you cannot add a c struct to an `NSArray`. You should wrap it in `NSValue` before adding it to an array. `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a c-struct. Check the [documentation here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html)

Change this:

```
[_routePoints addObject:_userLocation];
```

to:

```
NSValue *aValue = [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:_userLocation];
[_routePoints addObject:aValue];
```

To get the coordinate back from `NSValue`, you can use,

```
[aValue MKCoordinateValue];
```

As mentioned in your error message, you were trying to add `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to an array which expects an object.

Comment: The crash was not caused by the initial `NSLog(@"%@", _route.pointCount);` because the `NSLog(@"%@", _route.points);` line was before it, I reordered it after realizing that it was never getting to the `_route.pointCount` line. But I was ignorant enough to use `%@` before you corrected me. And my `initWithCenterCoordinate:` method says exactly that.

Comment: It would have crashed if you used it as shown in question. For second issue, are you sure you are using `(CLLocationCoordinate2D)` and not `(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)`?

Comment: Yes, I haven't deviated from the Apple sample code. I took the actual files and dropped them in my project, only adding `NSLog()` statements.

Comment: @HighFlyingFantasy, Got the issue. Updated the answer with the solution for that.

Comment: Much nicer than creating a useless wrapper class. Thank you.

Comment: Yup. NSValue itself is a wrapper class and you dont need a new one just for this. Thanks for accepting. Glad to help.

Comment: [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:..] is available from iOS 6 and up

Comment: You also need to `#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>` do be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever api you're using to talk to parse is expecting an id which is a pointer to any object. A cllocationcoordinate2d is a c-struct of two doubles and not an object if I'm not mistaken. You should probably create a little wrapper object to save those two doubles and convert them to/from CLLocationCoordinate2d items.

Comment: Yes. The wrapper should probably be PFGeoPoint.

Answer (score 0):

1:

Line: `NSLog(@"%@", _route.points)`; is wrong

_route.points is not a String, and you are using the NSStrig formating symbol "%@".

Further:

Since CLLocationCoordinate2D is a C-Sruct and not an Objective-C Object, you probaly want to create an own GeoPoint class.