# How do convert NSValue to CLLocationCoordinate?

Tags: ios, cllocation, nsvalue

I tried to store `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to `NSMutableArray` but I could only do it using `NSValue`. I want to get those coordinates stored in `NSMutableArray` in `NSValue` type as `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. How can I do that? I am having trouble getting those coordinates since it only pointers.

I tried to store using

```
[valueArray addObject:[CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(54.860812, -78.990710) ]]
```

it gives expected identifier error 
but I was successfully able to store using `NSValue` but I am not able to get the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` out of `NSValue`.

```
[valueArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(54.860717, -78.990722)]]; 
for (NSValue *object in valueArray)
{   
    NSLog(@"%@", object]
    //return pointers
}
```

I will appreciate if somebody can help me on this and suggest me which is a better approach of storing `CLLocation` in a mutable array.

Comment: This got marked as a duplicate, but that question doesn't seem to answer your question so I'll add that to get the coordinate back out the `NSValue` you want to use `object.MKCoordinateValue`

Comment: Thanks dan. Worked perfectly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14708590/467105, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328173/how-to-store-cllocationcoordinate2d, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926718/sending-cllocationcoordinate2d-to-parameter-of-incompatible-type-my-code-in-xcod, etc.  And there's always [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithMKCoordinate:).  The "See Also" for valueWithMKCoordinate: lists MKCoordinateValue.

Comment: #import <MapKit/MKGeometry.h>
NSValue *coordinateValue;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [coordinateValue MKCoordinateValue];

Comment: This is not duplicate.